# Ejecutar string query en consulta select from

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Buen día, ayuda, como puedo ejecutar esta query dentro  de un select from (@query)

```
declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(max) = 'select * from RegistroDeuda'

exec (@sqlQuery)
SELECT *
 FROM exec(@sqlQuery)    
WHERE 1 = 1
```

o en su defecto poder hacer algo como,

```
declare @where nvarchar(max) = 'where IdBanco = 2' 
SELECT * FROM RegistroDeuda + @where
```

Lo cual me arroja error de sintaxis también. Lo requiero así, ya que quiero declarar los campos en una variable para ser reutilizada. Agradezco su apoyo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No se puede incluir un `EXEC` dentro de un `SELECT`.

También es buena práctica usar el procedimiento almacenado sp_executesql para poder parametrizar las consultas. Pero lo mejor es evitar el código dinámico cuando sea posible porque aumenta la complejidad del código, su mantenimiento y disminuye la seguridad del sistema.

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(max) = 'select * from RegistroDeuda';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlQuery;
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, de esta forma tambien me arroja error de sintexis. declare miVar nvarchar(max) = 'IdBanco = 2'
SELECT * FROM RegistroDeuda miVar

Comment: El código que yo publiqué no tiene errores de sintaxis. Lo que pones en tu comentario no tiene sentido. Edita la pregunta para mostrar lo que estás haciendo

Comment: Tu código está bien, de hecho ejecuto varios query de esa forma, lo que no quisiera es declarar un string para ejecutar una consutla, en realidar lo que quisiera es hacer una consulta normal y utilizar un string que contiene las clausulas o los where. No sé si me hago entender.

Comment: No puedes combinar código dinámico con código estático. Tiene que ser todo o nada.